# Calling Content Script function on chrome.browserAction.onClicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

My question is fairly simple and I just want to figure out the easiest way to do this.

The current iteration of my chrome extension injects a DIV into the webpage with a button, which, when pressed, will execute a function.

I want to do this without injecting DIVs, by executing a function within one of my content scripts when the browser button is pressed in the toolbar. What's the simplest way to go about this? I believe I have to use the background page, and the only thing I see in documentation is registering some listening events on both ends. If this is the only/simplest way, how do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, contacting a content script from a browser or page action button is done using messages sent back and forth between the background script and the content script(s)

First step: Tell the background script what to do on browserAction/pageAction button click

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
   ...
});
```

Step 2: Inside the `browserAction.onClicked` event listener you can then send a message to the content script (in fact to any code listening!):

```
chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {<YOURMESSAGEPAYLOAD>});
```

Step 3: Inside the content script, you add a listener for incoming messages

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, callback) {
   // request contains the YOURMESSAGEPAYLOAD sent above as a Javascript object literal
});
```

You can also go the other way round and send messages from the content script to the background script by using the following inside the content script

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({<YOURMESSAGEPAYLOAD>});
```

and then use the `onMessage` listener inside the background script the same way as mentioned above.

Comment: The documentation doesn't say, but I assume that the `tab` argument to `onClicked` is the active tab.  This would let you get `tab.id` without needing `query`.

Comment: Indeed ... I changed the example accordingly

Comment: I know this is a bit late and thanks a million for this answer but it's addListener rather than addEventListener.

Comment: Hey all, can this be done other way round as well? Like from content script I want to call a method in my browser action page JS

Comment: Thanks @devnull69 you nearly suggested me a solution. I am trying to convert chrome extension into safari extension. XCode provides me readymade tools but some bridging knowledge will be required. Thanks again. Hopefully your solution helps here => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49103924/extensions-stops-execution-on-browser-browseraction-onclicked-addlistenerfunct

Answer (score 0):

devnull69 is correct, you need to use message passing. Also consider checking out [chromeps](https://github.com/anderspitman/chromeps). It's a small pubsub library I wrote for chrome extensions. Removes a lot of the overhead when writing message passing code.