# Creating a variable in a Chrome extension popup from a variable in the DOM

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I've dug through other answers for a while now but haven't found anything that I think quite does what I'm looking for, so it's time for my first stackoverflow question! (Be gentle, I started learning js about 3 weeks ago.)

The tl;dr here is that I'm looking to take a DOM element (innerHTML mostly) from the active tab on the page and, when my popup opens, use that element to populate links in specific ways.

For instance, using Twitter as an example, I'd like to grab the top tweet's permalink and have part of my extension's dropdown offer a link to that.

The way I'm seeing it working is with messaging (as referenced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25756807/calling-content-script-function-on-chrome-browseraction-onclicked) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19758028/chrome-extension-get-dom-content)), but something's escaping me.

My best guess from the above example and digging through some other scripts is the following in my main page's `content.js`; (I've already used `document.getElementById` to set the var `previousVariable`):

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (msg, sender, sendResponse) {

if (msg.text === 'report_back') {
    sendResponse(previousVariable.href);
    }
});
```

And then the following in my `popup.js`:

```
console.log("This is step one!");

function doStuffWithDom(domContent) {
    console.log('Did it work? ' + domContent);
}

// When the browser-action button is clicked...
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {text: 'report_back'}, doStuffWithDom);
});
```

Comment: browserAction.onClicked is only for the background page script and only when you don't have a popup html. In your case simply send a message at the start of popup.js or in its DOMContentLoaded callback.