# Extensions stops execution on browser.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(funct);

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

My browser extensions is simple one so far but there is an issue with manifest. In one case only browser button works, and on the other only script works.

background.js

```
function myfunction() { //change page text }
myfunction();

function onclicktest() { // do something on btn click }

browser.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(onclicktest);

alert('Never shown');
```

Case 1 - Browser button not working, myfunction gets called

```
"content_scripts":
[{
  "matches": ["<all_urls>"],      
  "js": ["background.js"],
  "run_at": "document_end"
}]
```

Case 2 - Browser button working, the myfunction doesn't get called

```
"background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
}
```

This is a Firefox add-on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because the `browserAction` API is not available to the content script environment and the code from `myfunction` that is supposed to modify a web page won't work when it is executed in the extension's background script.

You could make this work using something like this:

```
browser.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab){
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
        code: `(${myfunction.toString()})();`
    }
});
```

And the manifest.json:

```
"permissions":["tabs"],
"background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
}
```

Comment: Even if I write console.log("background script") as first statement in background.js then also the statement is not being printed. Would anyone let me know how I get confirmation of background script execution?

Comment: @PareshThakor Where are you looking for the log ? The background script runs in a special context that you can access by going to the `chrome://extensions` page and pressing the **Inspect views background page** link of your extension.

Comment: Correct @Titus I was looking into main console stuff then later I got that thing but in Safari we can select particular background script page to see its console.